# What must I do to clone all settings from one user to another one?

Tags: shortcut-keys, clone

I have set up a computer with a Xubuntu 22.04 system. I have installed all additional programs I want and I have configured the desktop, task bar, shortcuts, automatically started applications and so on.

Now I want to clone all these settings to a new user which I just have created.

1. Will it be sufficient to clone `~/.config`, `~/.local` and `.xsessionrc` from the first user to the new one and set access rights to them? (e.g. the same as they were given to the first installed user's files in those places)?
2. All scripts referenced in the first installation are in a special folder `Scripts` of the first user. I make this folder accessible to subsequently created users such that they can be used in scripts, e.g. for keyboard shortcut definitions.
3. Do I have to clone any other hidden files from the already working user's home directory itself to the newly created user?